# Is there any way to make a keyboard shortcut on an iPad to trigger a video screenshot?

Tags: ipad, ipados

The iPad external hardware keyboard supports Shift-Command-3 and Shift-Command-4 for image screenshots. Is there any way to do a keyboard shortcut for video screen captures as well?

Comment: Are you saying the those keyboard shortcuts don't capture a video screenshot on the iPad Pro keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any keyboard shortcut that specifically does video capture.

I have an iPad Pro 11 with the new Magic Keyboard.  Doing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> work as expected.

I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> and it has no effect, at least not the same result as on a Mac.

I can't find any documentation from Apple or 3rd-party sites that indicate how to do this, as of now.